# "channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused" error when I try to connect to Ubuntu server from my machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, server, localhost

"channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused" error when I try to connect to ubuntu server from my machine.

I am beginner in working with Ubuntu server. I tried to connect to an Ubuntu server from my laptop (which I was able to connect before) using "ssh -p 2225 -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8001 username@hostname" command, but unfortunately, I encountered the following error: channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused.

Can anyone help me.